# Chain last element of list with equal first element of another list

Tags: python, chain

this has had me occupied half of the afternoon already... I am trying to chain the last and first elements of a nested list. I'll illustrate this with an easy example:

```
input = [(8, 2), (8, 5), (2, 12), (12, 13), (5, 6), (6, 7), (13, 14), 
         (14, 3), (7, 4), (3, 4)]
result = [(8, 2), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7),
          (7, 6), (6, 5), (5, 8)]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
def ChainNew(L):
    R = copy.deepcopy(L)
    for pair in R:
        pair.reverse()
    stop = len(L)
    chain = [L.pop(0)]
    L = sorted(L)
    R = sorted(R)
    while len(chain) < stop:
        for i, j in zip(L, R):
            if i[0] == chain[len(chain)-1][1]:
                chain.append((i))
                L.remove(i)
                R.remove(i[::-1])
                break
            if j[0] == chain[len(chain)-1][1]:
                chain.append((j))
                L.remove(j[::-1])
                R.remove(j)
                break
    return chain
```

but not only is this *inefficient*, but it also is buggy: it doesn't seem to return all elements of the initial list. For example:

```
L =  [[20, 56], [23, 24], [23, 12], [22, 21], [26, 48], [26, 24],
      [55, 48], [55, 39], [56, 40], [19, 6], [19, 12], [6, 15],
      [40, 39], [21, 57], [14, 15], [14, 16], [57, 50], [45, 9],
      [45, 53], [18, 42], [18, 9], [38, 53], [38, 44], [50, 42],
      [16, 17], [17, 35], [36, 37], [36, 35], [37, 44]]

return = [[20, 56], [56, 40], [40, 39], [39, 55], [55, 48], [48, 26],
          [26, 24], [24, 23], [23, 12], [12, 19], [19, 6], [6, 15], 
          [15, 14], [14, 16], [16, 17], [17, 35], [35, 36], [36, 37], 
          [37, 44], [44, 38], [38, 53], [53, 45], [45, 9], [9, 18], 
          [18, 42], [42, 50], [50, 57]]
```

There must be an easier way of doing this...

**EDIT:** sorry! I forgot to mention that the the integers inside each list (pair) can be swapped. For example (7, 4) to (4, 7).

Basically what I have here in each pair of numbers are the indexes of an edge of a polyline. All the edges together form the polyline. So by "chaining" each pair of numbers, I can get the indexes of the vertices of a polyline in a sorted manner.

**EDIT AGAIN:**
The correct result of the list L would be:

```
return = [[22, 21], [21, 57], [57, 50], [50, 42], [42, 18], [18, 9],
          [9, 45], [45, 53], [53, 38], [38, 44], [44, 37], [37, 36],
          [36, 35], [35, 17], [17, 16], [16, 14], [14, 15], [15, 6],
          [6, 19], [19, 12], [12, 23], [23, 24], [24, 26], [26, 48],
          [48, 55], [55, 39], [39, 40], [40, 56], [56, 20]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to re-order your list so that the first element in the item, will be equal to the last element in the predecessor item?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it. Maybe that would make a better title for the question! :)

Comment: I think you're looking for an [Eulerian trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_trail) where your tuples describe edges on the graph (circuit if you want to wind up where you start).  There are lots of available implementations in Python to study.

Comment: I've added an answer but your example at the top of the post doesn't contain (4,7) in the input. So do you also want to *change* the order of the inner items?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention it. The elements inside each list can be swapped. I'm going to edit to question to clarify it.

Comment: But what is the order? I mean- if there's a choice between the original list and the swapped value - how does the algorithm choose? For example in your list, when it gets to '6' you can choose [6,15] or use the inverse for [19,6]..

Comment: If your goal is to make an ordering for the indices of a polyline then why not just decide an ordering function and order the indices by that?

Comment: Well they can be freely swapped. But the important thing is that in the end all numbers inside each pair an chained so that pair[1] == (pair+1)[0] AND the length resulting list is the same as the original list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. In any case, I don't have the polyline (it's what I am hoping to get in the end). I only have the edges and the indexes of the vertices of the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def path(a, b):
    if not b:
        return a
    for n, (p, q) in enumerate(b):
        if p == a[-1][1]:
            return path(a + [(p, q)], b[:n] + b[n+1:])
        if q == a[-1][1]:
            return path(a + [(q, p)], b[:n] + b[n+1:])
    raise ValueError("no path", a, b)

L = [(8, 2), (8, 5), (2, 12), (12, 13), (5, 6), (6, 7), (13, 14), (14, 3), (7, 4), (3, 4)]
print path([L[0]], L[1:])
#[(8, 2), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7), (7, 6), (6, 5), (5, 8)]
```

Comment: That seems to work great!. I'll have to study what you did, since I'm a bit of a rookie :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that finds all possible chains:

```
def find_chains(points):
    """For a list of points, take the first point and finds all chains that
    could be made from the following points.

    Returns a list of lists of tuples. Each sublist is a possible chain.
    """

    def find_solutions(start, choices):
        """For a starting point and a list of choices, return all choices that
        might succeed that point.

        Returns a list of tuples. These tuples contain the next choice, and all
        of the remaining points should that choice be used.
        """

        ret = []
        for i, possible_choice in enumerate(choices):
            # Determine whether or not the choice is appropriate.
            added_choice = None
            if start[1] == possible_choice[0]:
                added_choice = possible_choice
            elif start[1] == possible_choice[-1]:
                added_choice = possible_choice[::-1]

            # If it is, add a tuple of that choice and all other choices to the
            # return list.
            if added_choice:
                ret.append((
                    added_choice,
                    [
                        k
                        for j, k
                        in enumerate(choices)
                        if i != j
                    ]
                ))

        return ret

    solutions = []
    start = points[0]
    other_points = points[1:]
    if not other_points:
        # If there aren't any remaining points, then the only possible path is
        # that of just the first point.
        return [[start]]

    # Find all chains through `other_points` and add them to our solutions.
    for next_point, remaining_points in find_solutions(start, other_points):
        for subchain in find_chains([next_point] + remaining_points):
            solutions.append([start] + subchain)
    return solutions
```

The difference between this solution and other, shorter solutions is that the others just take the first possible point and find the subchain from there, whereas this one takes every possible point. Example:

```
test = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
print(find_chains(test))
# Finds two possible solutions:
# [[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)],
#  [(1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2)]]

test = [(8, 2), (8, 5), (2, 12), (12, 13), (5, 6), (6, 7), (13, 14),
        (14, 3), (7, 4), (3, 4)]
print(find_chains(test))
# Finds the only solution:
# [[(8, 2), (2, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7), (7, 6), (6, 5), (5, 8)]]

test = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(find_chains(test))
# There weren't any solutions:
# []
```

Comment: Great! At the moment all the polylines I have are open not self-intersecting. In the future I guess I could find your code to be useful to detect such self-intersections events.